# Определение слоя для UI элемента

Tags: xml, android, ui

Добрый день.

Создаю RelativeLayout, на котором располагается 3 элемента `ImageView`. Один выравниваю по верхней границе родителя `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`, второй по нижней `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, третий располагается в центре во весь экран `(android:layout_width="match_parent", android:layout_height="match_parent",  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true", android:layout_centerVertical="true")`

Каким образом я могу передвинуть первые два элемента поверх третьего? какое свойство за это отвечает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше просто запомнить правило:
вьюхи, описанные в xml файле, создаются по очереди. это значит, что чем выше в xml файле описана вьюха, тем ниже она будет по иерархии.

в твоем конкретном случае сначала нужно описать тот **ImageView**, который занимает весь экран, а после него описать верхний и нижний. тогда они будут расположены поверх первого **ImageView**.

Comment: Т.е. специального свойства для этого не предусмотрено? Все равно спасибо, помогло

Comment: на самом деле есть свойство: bringToFront, но я бы не советовал его использовать: если есть связи типа align_left, right и т.д, то это свойство рушит связи (у меня пару раз с этим косяки были). и еще это свойство не работает c упорядоченными контейнерами (LinearLayout например)